# Do we develop with iOS 8.2 or 8.3 for Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, apple-watch

I'm having a weird issue on 8.2 in my Apple Watch app, but it's working fine in 8.3. Which are we supposed to be developing with if we want to release an Apple Watch app for launch?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your app's shipping time.
Right now, ios 8.3 is still in beta, that means you cannot release your app if you using xcode 6.3 and swift 1.2.
However, I believe that Apple will release ios 8.3 in WWDC 2015, mid June. Therefore, if your schedule is after that, you should stick with ios 8.3.

Just my 2 cents.